# org.axonframework.commandhandling.distributed.CommandDispatchException:An erroroccurredwhiletryingtodispatchacommandontheDistributedCommandBus:404null

Tags: microservices, netflix-eureka, axon

***Facing below issue:
org.axonframework.commandhandling.distributed.CommandDispatchException: An error occurred while trying to dispatch a command on the DistributedCommandBus: 404 null

The application is deployed on open shift platform using K8s.
This issue is coming while increasing the number of pods to greater than 1 on a specific environment.***

Below is the configuration file:-

```
    eventbus:
      type: jms
    eventBus:
      server:
        selector:
          topicName: EventBus
          queueName: EventBus.management-inventory-api
    eventstore:
      jdbc:
        validateOnly: true
    endpoints:
      health:
        sensitive: false
      jmx:
        uniqueNames: true
    
    liquibase:
      enabled: false
    server:
      port: 8087
      http:
        port: 8088
      ssl:
        enabled: false
        keyStore: ${certs.path}/inventorydomain.jks
        keyStoreType: JKS
        trustStore: ${certs.path}/inventorydomain_truststore.jks
        trustStoreType: JKS
        keyAlias: inventorydomain
    
    spring:
      jmx:
        default-domain: com.inventory.domain.inventory-command
      jpa:
        hibernate:
          ddlAuto: validate
        show-sql: true
      messages:
        basename: errors,platform-errors
      autoconfigure.exclude: |
        org.axonframework.boot.autoconfig.JpaAutoConfiguration,
        org.axonframework.boot.autoconfig.AxonAutoConfiguration
    annotation:
      eventHandler:
        lookupPrefix: com.consumercard.command.listener.external
      eventMapping:
        lookupPrefix: com.consumercard.command.event
    jmsBrokers:
      producer:
        brokerUrl: vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false
      consumer:
        brokerUrl: vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false
    
    spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled: false
    eureka:
      instance:
        preferIpAddress: true
        nonSecurePort: ${server.http.port}
        securePort: ${server.port}
        nonSecurePortEnabled: true
        securePortEnabled: false
        metadata-map:
          zone: zone-1
      client:
        enabled: false
        serviceUrl:
          defaultZone: https://localhost:8448/eureka
    logging:
      level: DEBUG
    
    basicAuth.enabled: true
    
    rest:
      client:
        connection:
          defaultMaxPerRoute: 50
          maxTotal: 100
          connectionTimeout: 10000
          readTimeout: 30000
```

NOTE:-

```
This was an additional property added:-
    eureka:
      instance:  
        metadata-map:
          zone: zone-1
```

Comment: Hi @Gunjan0511, I'd like to ask you to add additional information to your ticket. So, if you could add the following, I'm certain we can help you better: Axon Framework version, Axon Spring Cloud Extension version, Spring (Boot) version, JDK version, Any Axon configuration (the above contains none).

Comment: Furthermore, does the above work if you're not running in Kubernetes? Lastly, have you checked Axon's sample project for distributing commands with the Spring Cloud Extension? If not, you can find it here -> https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-springcloud-sample